# Returning memory stream from function

Tags: c#

In your opinions, is it better to return a newly allocated memory stream from a function, or pass it into the function?  For instance,

```
void Foo(MemoryStream m) 
{ 
   m.Write(somebuffer, 0, somebuffer.Length); 
}
```

or

```
void MemoryStream Foo()
{
    MemoryStream retval = new MemoryStream();
    retval.Write(somebuffer, 0, somebuffer.Length);
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of good answers here, but none of them addresses why VS 2010 gives a CA2000 reliability warning for the second form. You can't very well dispose of an object you intend to return, and to dispose of it after it is returned seems awkward. Makes me think the first form is preferred.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a bit like asking whether you should return a string from a method or take a StringBuilder and append to it. The answer depends on what the use case is.

Is it likely that the caller will want to call your method with an existing stream containing some data? Might they want to call it several times using the same stream? If so, the version taking the MemoryStream would be more efficient. On the other hand, if they only want the data once, returning it as a MemoryStream (or, more simply, as a byte array) may well be more appropriate.

Unfortunately from the description we can't really tell what's going on. Of course, you could implement both as overloads and call one from the other.

Answer (score 8):

**Passing** a memory stream into a function and **returning** a memory stream for a function shouldn't be used interchangeably. The methods you describe serve two different purposes.

- Passing something to a function is for when you want the function to do something with the parameter.
- Returning something from a function is when the caller is supposed to do something with the result.

You are talking about two different things, apples and oranges.

Answer (score 5):

I would always pass the stream into the function. This allows it to work with any stream of the caller's choosing, for example straight into a file without any buffering.

Comment: Then how come there are so many methods returning a stream? ;-) Usualy named Open... or GetStream ... I think it depends on what's the purpose of the stream.

Comment: Because that is **opening**/**creating** a stream. It isn't clear whether your method is creating a stream vs pushing data into one. The two things have different answers.

Comment: Returning a stream one shows that they are not expecting anything inside.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely return it from the function. You have to call `Dispose()` or put it inside a `using` clause because it implements IDisposable.

Comment: Calling Dispose on a MemoryStream doesn't do anything. It doesn't acquire any unmanaged resources.

Comment: @Merhdad & Jon - Not always true. If you have used any of the async methods on the stream it will be caching a WaitHandle and then the Dispose method does do something. So you're safer to dispose of it unless you *know* no async methods have been, or ever will be, called.

Comment: FYI - unless you really, really, really care that this is MemoryStream, you should be returning a Stream object.

Comment: @Mehrdad & Jon on the other hand, it doesn't hurt to be in the habit of disposing your streams (since afaik more of the standard ones require disposal than don't)

Comment: @Greg: Good point, although I can't say I often use memory streams in an async way myself. Another time when it matters is when it's a remote stream. @John: Agreed. (There's a separate question entirely about this, btw. Importantly though, disposing it *doesn't* free the memory involved.)

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it's overemphasized. I've never used any async methods on a MemoryStream. I prefer Jeff's approach: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001211.html

Comment: Usually you need to call dispose on objects that are received from static functions, for IDisposable objects recieved from other objects it's API specific, and the API must specify what should be done with the received stream.

Comment: @Merdad - By not disposing it you're relying on an implementation detail to keep your code efficient rather than a contract. That's entirely your choice, but it's not the type of choice I like to make.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That blog post is bad IMO. Calling Dispose *isn't* an optimisation - for most types it's needed for *correctness* rather than performance.

Comment: @Greg: I think it's reasonable to assume that MemoryStream won't have any associated unmanaged resources when used synchronously in process. It's not a case of keeping the code efficient, it's a case of occasionally it being a lot easier to *not* have to keep track of ownership.

Comment: @Jon: I believe the blog post basically says the same thing as you just said: "remember: you could always terminate them with extreme prejudice, if you feel it's necessary." The keyword is "if". This specific case usually doesn't satisfy this criteria while most other types clearly do.

Answer (score 1):

Your second one is better.  I always try to avoid mutating objects inside functions if at all possible.

Comment: Streams are *supossed* to be mutated that's why they are streams and not immutable arrays. And also passing a stream to a Save, or Export, or WriteXXX method is pretty common in my opinion ...

Comment: There are lots of objects that are "supposed" to be mutated.  However if you are going to initialize the object completely in the function why not have the function return the reference to the object rather than providing the reference?

Comment: @Andrew: Because you might want to append to the data that's already there, for instance. Note that the sample code doesn't reinitialize the existing stream - it just writes more data to it.

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean.  It seemed like the question was implying that the caller would instantiate the MemoryStream and then immediately pass it into the function.  I can see the benefit of both approaches but which one is better depends on how they are used. :)

Answer (score 1):

After some more thought, I think it comes down to the intended semantics of the `Foo` method.  Is it:

- An operation that creates a stream (eg. `File.Open()`)
- An operation that modifies a stream (eg. `something.WriteXml()`)

If the answer is "creates a stream", have it return a stream.  If it modifies a stream, pass the stream in.

If the answer is "some of both", it may make sense to split the method so that it has only a single responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't two many differences.  In the first instance the caller will have control over the memory stream and in the second instance, you can do something like this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = Foo())
{
  //Do Stuff here.
}
```

The most important thing is to remember to dispose of it correctly.

Comment: MemoryStream is purely a managed object. Calling Dispose wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @Merhdad - Not always true. If you have used any of the async methods on the stream it will be caching a WaitHandle and then the Dispose method does do something. So you're safer to dispose of it unless you *know* no async methods have been, or ever will be, called.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the injected form.  It removes the direct coupling between your code and the MemoryStream and it makes it more testable.

```
public void Foo(Stream stream)
{
    stream.Write(somebuffer, 0, somebuffer.Length);
}
```

Now I can test Foo with any class that implements Stream including a mock class.

Typically, I would do the injection in the constructor of the class rather than on individual methods but the idea is basically the same.

```
public class FooClass
{
   public Stream FooStream { get; private set; }

   public FooClass() : this(null) { }

   public FooClass( Stream stream )
   {
       // provide a default if not specified
       this.FooStream = stream ?? new MemoryStream();
   }

   public void Foo()
   {
       this.FooStream.Write( somebuffer, 0, somebuffer.Length );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tend towards the first for two reasons:

1. The semantics of who "owns" the memory stream are clear.  The caller created it, so it's up to the caller to get rid of it (this is more of an issue with other types of streams that hold on to unmanaged resources)
2. `Foo` can be used in conjunction with other methods that operate on your stream

That said, if the main purpose of `Foo` is as a factory method for MemoryStreams (similar to something like File.Open, etc.), the second approach makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Because streams are resources that need explicit disposal (memory, file, network) it is best to apply a RAII approach to handling them. That means that the function that initializes them must be responsible with the release (we have "using" keyord in C# just for that). To enable this pattern i say accepting the stream as a parameter. That way the caller can decide when to create and dispose the stream. While you're at it make your method accept any stream implementation; it does not seem like it needs to work only for MemoryStream.